# How to choose pixel size while doing interpolation in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, interpolation, tin

How do you choose pixel size X and Y while doing TIN interpolation? What determines the size?

Comment: By the documentation https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/interpolation.html it is "Output raster size".

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't get what it determines the optimal pixel size.

Comment: The primary TIN is vector format and thus without resolution. It is up to you to decide the pixel size  as documented `You have to declare the output extent by either choosing it from the map canvas, selecting it from another layer or type it manually.` You probably know something about the accuracy of the source data so you can base your selection on that knowledge.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!! Have a nice day.